# Parse value of php variable to HTML input field

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to parse the value of a php variable to an HTMl input field (*element_5*). Right now I just want to write out the user input from *element_1* to this field. This is just a dummy function that will later be replaced by a python script.
However, when I click on the *submi*t button there is no output in the field *element_5* and the content of all other files disappears as well.
Can you check where I go wrong?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php
    function display()
    {
    $val=$_POST['element_1'];
    echo '<id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'. $val .'">';
    //echo $val;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       display();
    } 
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Policy Lookup</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >
    
    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">
    
        <h1><a>Policy Lookup</a></h1>
        <form id="form_26900" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="form.php">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Policy Lookup</h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >
            
                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Source IP </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Destination IP </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Drop Down </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_4" name="element_4"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1" >TCP</option>
<option value="2" >UDP</option>
<option value="3" >ICMP</option>
<option value="4" >IP</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Destination Port </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>
            
                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="26900" />
                
                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
        <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="element_5">Result </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" readonly/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       
            </ul>
        </form> 
        <div id="footer">
            Generated by <a href="http://www.phpform.org">pForm</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've gotten an answer that gives you a solution to the issue, but I just want to point out that where you output elements matters. Your current code will output the element before the HTML document (and outside of the form). HTML (just like XML) is hierarchical. If you for example want elements to be part of a form, you need to put that element between the opening `<form>` and  closing `</form>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo '<id="element_5"` would need to be `echo '<input id="element_5"`. But that will duplicate the box you've already got lower down, and also it would be outside the `<html>` tag, making it invalid (because it's not part of the HTML document), so the browser is not obliged to show it.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$val = null;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $val = $_POST['element_1'];
} 
?>
```

and on the element further down the page:

```
<input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo ($val != null ? $val : ""); ?>" readonly/>
```

Note the inline PHP there to echo $val if it's not null.

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the explanation.